# How to disable Google Schemas

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I would be interested to know if there is the possibility to deactivate the email markup for gmail, because it happens that in some situations Gmail puts one that is not correct in terms of the information it shows.

Our application does not have the email markup set when sends an email, but Gmail does it its own way and with errors.

Regards.